# Completion of $(k[x_1, \dots, x_n]/I)_{(x_1, \dots , x_n)/I}$ is $k[[x_1, \dots , x_n ]] / Ik[[x_1, \dots , x_n ]]$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Seems simple question but don't know to prove rigorously.

In Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra book, in chapter 7, p.179 he wrote that "More generally, if $k$ is a field and $R:=k[x_1, \dots , x_n]/I$, then the completion of $R$ with respect to $\mathfrak{m}:=(x_1, \dots , x_n)$  ( $\mathfrak{m} \supseteq I$ ) is the ring $k[[x_1, \dots , x_n ]] / Ik[[x_1, \dots , x_n ]]$."

Why this is true?

And my associated question is,

**Q.** First, consider localization $R_{\mathfrak{m}/I} = (k[x_1, \dots, x_n]/I)_{\mathfrak{m}/I}$. Second, then, the completion of the local ring $R_{\mathfrak{m}/I}$ ( at the maximal ideal ) is $k[[x_1, \dots , x_n ]] / Ik[[x_1, \dots , x_n ]]$ ?

This question originates from trial to understand following proof in the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry book, Proposition 6.23 :

[image]

(If further information is needed ( e.g. definition of smoothness etc. ), I will upload.)

$\divideontimes$ Here, the Lemma 6.22 noted in the proof is,

[image]

If our question is true, then we maybe show the underlined statement as ( C.f. $x = (T_1, \dots,  T_n)$ )

$$\hat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,x} = \hat{\mathcal{O}}_{V(f_1, \dots f_r) ,x} = ((k[T_1, \dots , T_n]/(f_1, \dots , f_r))_{(T_1, \dots , T_n)/(f_1, \dots , f_r)})^{\wedge} \overset{!}{\cong} k[[T_1, \dots , T_n ]] / (f_1,\dots, f_r) k[[T_1, \dots , T_n ]] \cong k[[U_{r+1}, \dots , U_n]].$$

(  I think that the introduction of the notation $\hat{\mathcal{O}}_{\mathbb{A}^n_k,x}$ is redundant  ).

Can anyone help? Thanks for reading.